# How to separate input strings?

Tags: python

i'm coding a question, Thus:

```
def fuel():
    while True:
        try:
            prompt = input('Fraction: ')
            print(prompt.split())
            for spl in prompt:
                first = prompt[0]
                second = prompt[2]
            if first.isdigit() and second.isdigit() and prompt[1] == '/' :
                first = int(first)
                second = int(second)
                if(int(first)==first) and (int(second)==second):
                    answer = round(first / second,2)  
                    if answer < 1:
                        print('E')     
                    elif answer == 1:
                        print('F')
                    else:
                        print(f'{int(answer)}%')
                break
            
        except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError, IndexError):
            pass
fuel()
```

this is my code, i give it an input as two number and a '/' divide sign like >> x/y

the problem is when i enter 100/100, it answer will be 101 that starts the loop again,
anyway users input will be x/y, how can i get x and y value, regardless of its numerical value

that I can perform any operation on two numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use split() function with '/' as the separator, and we can can map a conversion to int like:

```
inp = list(map(int,input().split('/')))
```

giving an input of '7/10' has a result as a list: [7, 10]. the 2 values can be accessed by its index like inp[0] -> 7.

an other approach can be the use of the python fractions module. this works with a string input, and stores the fraction as an object

```
from fractions import Fraction as frac
fract1 = frac(input())
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

```
x, y = input().split("/")
```

The `.split()` function is very good for things like these. Even just leaving the brackets empty can split a string into a list (separating the spaces). Make sure to make your variables integers too!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use `sp = prompt.split(sep='/')` and then assign x and y as sp[0] and sp[1] respectively?